Is the refurbished Poison Spray now better at dealing damage than Fire Bolt?
In 2024, poison spray was upgraded from a range of 10 feet to 30 feet, and from a Con Save to avoid the damage, to a spell attack roll.
I've rarely seen poison spray used in play under the 2014 rules (and never from a player character), as the combination of the Con save, the ultra-short range, and the fact that lots of creatures are either resistant or immune to poison was just too punishing.
30 feet is still pretty short, compared to fire bolt's 120 feet, but at least to some extent now helps you target opponents while being in the back rank. How does the expected damage measure up?
I am asking to compare the expected damage output of 2024 fire bolt to 2024 poison spray.

It seems like a big part of the answer here will depend on the distribution of Poison vs Fire resistance.  Is this known before the Feb release of MM?  Is it expected to be largely the same as MToF and MotM?

@Kirt I think it's reasonable to do a comparison that assumes no resistances or equally common resistances, and then revisit when the MM is published.

@Kirt I’ve said this before, but making character decisions based on average distribution of monsters properties is a really poor way to make decisions, so resistance distributions isnt really important for a good answer here.

I make decisions like that in PF 2e all the time.  I don't think it's invalid in principle in 5e, either, although the lack of information makes it imponderable for the moment.  But I am confused:  What is the actual obstacle to the very high rep OP answering the question immediately?

@Novak I did not manage to do so yesterday as I did not have the time to do the investigation, but you of course are right, so here you go.

@NobodytheHobgoblin I hope my comment did not come across as aggressive as it now seems in retrospect.  It just seemed out of character with questions you ask, and I was genuinely wondering what I was missing.

@Novak No problem, all well. In fact your observation was right.

Fire bolt still wins on damage
While the new Monster Manual is not out, the legacy monsters and their resistances still are what we use with the new rules. If those change materially, then this answer will need to be updated when the new MM comes out.
The average chance to hit with a melee or spell attack is about 65% throughout all levels of play, and this now is equal for both spells, so we can ignore it. The average resulting damage on a hit after accounting for fire resistance, vulnerability and immunity is 90%, and for poison it is 75% up to CR 10, and 80% or 63% for all CRs up to 20.1 Both cantrips scale the same way, so for simplicity we are using the base damage for comparison).
That means for tier 1 and 2 play (where more than 90% of all play happens):

Fire Bolt: d10 * 90% = 4.95
Poison Spray d12 * 75% = 4.875

And for a campaing spanning all tiers:

Fire Bolt: d10 * 80% = 4.4
Poison Spray d12 * 63% = 4.095

So, fire bolt still does more damage on average (ever so slightly in tier one).

1 This answer makes use of how common resistances are, by tabulating all monsters in the Monster Manual and averaging the results. Obviously, you are not fighting every monster in the book one time, so this is only an approximation of what you can expect. When the distribution of monsters in your campaign differs materially from this, than this will influence what the better cantrip is. For example if your campaign is all about fighting the Yuan-Ti in the jungles of Ket, all of whom are immune to poison damage, then go with fire bolt.

So we should pit more fire resistant/immune enemies to fix this. Gotcha.

This answer shows a fundamental confusion over probability and expected damage. First it assumes that the chance of each monster appearing in a given campaign is equal: it is not. Not only because the particular monsters that appear is a choice, not a random event, but also because most adventures are themed - the appearance of say orcs in the first room, increases the chance of orcs later on. A more fundamental flaw is that you multiply the expected damage by the average reduction across all monsters. At any given time a monster is resistant/immune or it isn’t, you can’t just do this.

@DaleM Could you clarify your last point? What would be the reasonable comparison in your opinion? In any specific encounter, if you were to have both cantrips available, this would be nonsensical, but I understand the question to aim for a general metric of which one can be generally expected to be more useful without any specific info. Or is there any technical mistake I'm overlooking?

@JE the problem is that it is applying probably to what is not a probalistic problem, it’s a game theory problem - if the DM knows I have Poison Spray will that influence their decisions about the monsters they include?

And more to the point, a player won't just stupidly cast Poison Spray at everything they see. Like, most undead are immune to poison, so you aren't going to use Poison Spray on those targets (or not more than once). Modifying the average damage by the relative numbers of monsters isn't a useful metric. At best the monster counts could generate the advice "you should have a backup attack if your favorite one isn't useful", but every player should follow that, from Sorcerers to Fighters. Poison Spray may be useful slightly less often on average, but not so much that it's really notable.
